# How to provide row updates to table in Azure SQL DW using SSDT?

Tags: sql, azure, azure-synapse

How can I implement automated row updates using SSDT for table in AZURE SQL Datawarehouse? When I try using the OLEDB Command component I receive an error :

> An OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0" Hresult: 0x80004005 Description: "Stored procedure sp_describe_undeclared_parameters does not exist or is not supported.

I need to setup a table that is a SCD so require the update to be handled through SSDT. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am reading this correctly Ankit I believe you are trying to process the dimension using the Slowly changing dimension wizard in SSIS and are using the OLEDB Command component to process incremental updates to rows. Is that correct?

May I suggest you take a different approach. Consider loading the data into SQLDW in full. Depending on the size of the dimension either recreate the table in full and rename or perform an upsert on the table. Both can be implemented using CTAS.

Take a look at the merge example in the following article by way of example https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-data-warehouse-develop-ctas/

Comment: Hello JRJ, Thanks for that response. I came to the same realisation and used CTAS followed up Update to end up with the final table. Thanks.